# Bypass "Array is too big" python error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a csv file which contains more than 200 000 lines of meteo data. When I want to model the data with `matplotlib`, this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try4.py", line 19, in <module>
    X,Y = meshgrid( data_x,data_y )   
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3378, in  meshgrid
    mult_fact = np.ones(shape, dtype=int)   
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 148, in ones
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order) 
  ValueError: array is too big.
```

I found out that a file with 5000 lines max can be processed. 
How can I bypass the error in order to process all the file of 200000 lines?
Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from pylab import *


# read CSV as a numpy array
data = mlab.csv2rec('datasets/mix.csv')

# print CSV file headers
print data.dtype.names

# load columns as vectors
data_x = data['longitude']
data_y = data['latitude']
data_u = data['x']
data_v = data['y']

X,Y = meshgrid( data_x,data_y )
U = cos(data_u)
V = sin(data_v)


# plot raw data
Q = quiver( X, Y, U, V, units='width')
qk = quiverkey(Q, 0.5, 0.92, 2, '.', labelpos='W',
               fontproperties={'weight': 'bold'})
title('Current Surface')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What does an array element look like? This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652650/matplotlib-plot-array-size-limit seems to think that there isn't an obvious array limit (and if so at least at 1m+ elements)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Here is an example
 //headers  X,    Y,    Latitude,   Longitude, VOGRD_201304100000  
 //data 292,    1,    0.000000,  -50.530000,            0                ...and 200 000 other lines like that

Comment: Can you give more information? Which `matplotlib` calls are you using, etc.

Comment: @tiago I import numpy, pyplot, mlab and pyplat. I want to plot current surface's data so I'm catching x, y, latitude and longitude and I manipulate it with quiver's function.

Comment: Please show us some code. We're not sure what you're doing that causes this.

Comment: @brice my post has been edited

Comment: Can you also show us the _full_ error you get?

Comment: The error is coming up from `numpy`, not `matplotlib`.  Are you using 32bit or 64bit windows?

Comment: @tcaswell I'm using 32bit windows

Comment: I think you maybe running into the limits of 32bit addressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*why* are you using `meshgrid` ([doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html))?  It well generate a 200k by 200k array which will not match the dimensions of your `u` and `v` data.  I think you want to do this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from pylab import *


# read CSV as a numpy array
data = mlab.csv2rec('datasets/mix.csv')

# print CSV file headers
print data.dtype.names

# load columns as vectors
data_x = data['longitude']
data_y = data['latitude']
data_u = data['x']
data_v = data['y']

U = cos(data_u)
V = sin(data_v)


# plot raw data
Q = quiver(data_x, data_y, U, V, units='width')
qk = quiverkey(Q, 0.5, 0.92, 2, '.', labelpos='W',
               fontproperties={'weight': 'bold'})
title('Current Surface')
```